# PUGXMultiUserBundle Container error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, pugxmultiuserbundle

i installed PUGXMultiUserBundle using this [documentation](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) and i follow this, but i have an error

Type error: Argument 1 passed to FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface, none given...
[image]

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: AppBundle\Entity\User
service:
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager
from_email:
        address: "%mailer_user%"
        sender_name: "%mailer_user%"
pugx_multi_user:
users:
      simple_user:
          entity:
              class: AppBundle\Entity\SimpleUser
          registration:
              form:
                  type: AppBundle\Form\SimpleUserType
                  name: fos_user_registration_form
                  validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
              template: AppBundle:Registration:simple_user.form.html.twig
society_user:
          entity:
              class: AppBundle\Entity\SocietyUser
          registration:
              form:
                  type: AppBundle\Form\SocietyUserType
                  name: fos_user_registration_form
                  validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
              template: AppBundle:Registration:society_user.form.html.twig
```

and this is my RegistrationSimpleUserController:

```
/**
 * Class RegistrationSimpleUserController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 *
 */
class RegistrationSimpleUserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     *
     *
     * @Route("/register/simple", name="registration_simple_user")
     */
    public function registerAction()
    {
        return $this->container
            ->get('pugx_multi_user.registration_manager')
            ->register('Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne');
    }
}
```

Comment: Which symfony version are you using?

Comment: i use symfony 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug in the PUGX bundle which is not up to date.

They define the FOSUserBundle Registration controller as a service like this:

```
pugx_multi_user.registration_controller:
      class: FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController
```

But the RegistrationController in the FOSUserBundle has some dependencies:

```
public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
    $this->userManager = $userManager;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

I think you can solve it by defining an alias like this:

```
pugx_multi_user.registration_controller:
     alias: fos_user.registration.controller
```

Or overriding the whole definition in your own services.yml:

```
pugx_multi_user.registration_controller:
  class: FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController
  arguments:
        - '@event_dispatcher'
        - '@fos_user.registration.form.factory'
        - '@fos_user.user_manager'
        - '@security.token_storage'
```

Comment: It's work, but my template is still the fosuser registration , not my society_user.form.html.twig or simple_user.form.html.twig

Comment: Check the value you pass to ->register('Acme\UserBundle\Entity\UserOne') that is still the example value, should be: "AppBundle\Entity\SimpleUser" i guess ?